# How to check if a relation exists with a condition that the column for the latest record in the relation must be null?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: `offers` and `messages`. `offers` can have several `messages`. This is the relation code:

```
public function latestMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class, 'seller_id', 'seller_id')->latest();
}
```

I want to get only the `offers` whose latest message must not have been read.

```
Offer::whereHas('latestMessage', fn($query) => $query->whereNull('read'))->paginate(100);
```

But the `whereHas` just checks if any of the record is not read instead of checking the latest one. How do I make sure `whereHas` always checks the latest record?

Comment: Try using [`->latestOfMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) if you indeed have many messages and only want to get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `->latestOfMany()` works.

```
public function latestMessage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class, 'seller_id', 'seller_id')->latestOfMany();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Offer::whereHas('latestMessage', fn($query) => $query->latest('id')->whereNull('read'))->paginate(100);
```

Remove latest from relation.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get same results.

Comment: Try OrderBy() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your relation class as below

**if your relation is hasMany then use below function**

```
public function latestMessage(){
      return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'seller_id', 'seller_id')->whereNull('read')->orderByDesc('created_at');
}
```

**if your relation is hasOne then use below function**

```
public function latestMessage(){
      return $this->hasOne(Message::class, 'seller_id', 'seller_id')->whereNull('read')->latestOfMany();
}
```

please try this and let us know if its working or not